# 一定時間が経過したら自動的に、ユーザーの投稿したデータを削除したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Twitterのようなユーザーが投稿できるSNSサイトを作っています。 
具体的には、Ruby on Rails Tutorialのサンプルアプリケーション完成直後で今から機能を足そうとしている段階です。 
ユーザーが投稿してから、一定時間（30分）が経過したら自動的にデータを削除する機能を実装したいです。

いろいろ調べて、wheneverを使って試してみたり、expires_inを使って試してみたりしたのですが、具体的な書き方が分からずどうしても消せません。

wheneverの場合だと、schedule.rbにどのように書けば良いか。 
また、その他に方法があれば是非教えてください。

大変お手数ですが、ご回答いただけますと助かります。

Comment: 参考になさったのはこちらでしょうか https://railstutorial.jp/

Comment: そうです！宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/66535

Answer (score 0):

一定時間が経過したら自動的にデータベースからデータを削除するのではなく、erbで一定時間が経過した投稿は表示させないとするほうが、実装しやすいのではないでしょうか。